# Markup is visible when I view sample data from my template

Tags: templates

I am just getting into Wordpress and I need your help. I have recently downloaded a template and I have uploaded the sample data but when I go to modify my template I notice that the markup is mixed in with the sample data.

Any ideas as to how to rectify this?

Much appreciated!